# Is rightshifting signed int by 8 * sizeof(int) or more undefined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

I know that this is undefined:

```
uint32_t u = 1;
u << 32;
```

But I'm a little bit confused about which kinds of shifts are undefined.

Is it undefined to shift a signed integer by it's size (in bits) or more to the right?

**Update:** As pointed out in the answer, this is about the size in bits, not in bytes.

Comment: What did you find by a simple google search for "C shift operators"? The Wikipedia entry already answers your question.

Comment: @Olaf I read about differences between signed and unsigned somewhere, so I was not sure.

Comment: Well, someone less friendly would have told you to RTFineM in the first place. You are required to show reasonable reseearch effort in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof (int)` is the size of `int` *in bytes*, so it's not relevant. What's relevant is not the size, but the *width*, which is the number of value bits in the representation (plus the sign bit for signed types).

If the right operand of a `<<` or `>>` operator is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined. (For example, if the left operand is of type `short`, it's promoted to `int` before the operation is applied).

For the `<<` left-shift operator, the behavior is defined only if the left operand is non-negative and the result is representable.

For the `>>` right-shift operator, the result is implementation-defined if the left operand is negative.

This is all defined in section 6.5.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to N1570, the most recent publicly available C11 draft).

Here's the full description of the semantics:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The 
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value 
>   of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the 
>   width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of **`E1 << E2`** is **`E1`** left-shifted **`E2`** 
>   bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If **`E1`** 
>   has an unsigned type, the value of the result is **`E1`** × 
>   **`2`**<sup>**`E2`**</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum 
>   value representable in the result type. If **`E1`** has a signed type 
>   and nonnegative value, and **`E1`** × **`2`**<sup>**`E2`**</sup> is
>   representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; 
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of **`E1 >> E2`** is **`E1`** right-shifted **`E2`** bit 
>   positions. If **`E1`** has an unsigned type or if **`E1`** has a signed 
>   type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral 
>   part of the quotient of **`E1`** / **`2`**<sup>**`E2`**</sup>. If 
>   **`E1`** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value 
>   is implementation-defined.

Comment: Assume 32-bit `int` (2's, no padding).  Does `INT_MIN >> 31` fall under "greater than or equal to the width" so UB or "implementation-defined if the left operand is negative"?

Comment: @chux Width is including the sign bit http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p6...

Comment: @chux: No, the *width* of a signed type includes the sign bit, so `INT_MIN >>  31` is well defined. (The term *width* is defined in N1570 6.2.6.2p6; it includes both value bits and any sign bit.) And I just edited my answer to reflect that. (I had forgotten that *width* includes the sign bit; the *precision* counts just the value bits.)

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the standard.  The [Section 6.5.7p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3)

> 3) The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value
>   of the right operand is negative **or is greater than or equal** to the
>   width of the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined**.

This applies for both left and right shifts, and for both signed and unsigned operands on the left side of the operator. There are additional constraints on shifting signed operands.

Comment: The part you quoted is correct, but there's more. The rules are different for left and right shifts.  Read paragraphs 4 and 5.

Comment: This part is the only relevant for the question "Is it undefined to shift a signed integer by it's size or more to the right?". And the answer is "yes, it is undefined", unconditionally, regardless of type.

Comment: Fair enough -- but the OP also said, "But I'm a little bit confused about which kinds of shifts are undefined."

Answer (score 0):

The C language was in wide use before the C89 Standard was written, and the authors of the C89 Standard did not want to impose any requirements for corner-case semantics which might be contrary to anything that existing implementations were already doing.

Some implementations will behave badly when given a very large or negative
shift amount (e.g. I think on a Transputer a shift of -1 will take about
4294967295 clock cycles to execute, during which time interrupts will be
disabled), and some implementations when asked to shift by the word length
won't shift at all.  The writers of the Standard saw no reason to distinguish between those behaviors, and simply regarded the word size as the threshold beyond which it would impose no requirements.

Although the proper meaning for negative values is unclear when using formats
other than two's-complement, there is no real ambiguity with two's-complement
values beyond the fact that some existing implementations use logical right-
shift rather than arithmetic right-shift even with signed types and the
Committee didn't want to mandate that any existing compilers change behavior
that code might be relying upon it.  When using negative values in formats
other than two's-complement, it's unclear what shifts in either direction
should mean, but the Committee thought it more likely that there might exist
a machine that would do something weird when left-shifting a negative number
than that a machine might do something weird when right-shifting a negative
number.

Note that the notion that a quality compiler given something like:

```
unsigned long rotate_left(unsigned long dat, int amount)
{ return (dat << amount) | (dat >> (32-amount)); }
```

should do anything other than yield "dat" when amount==0 [note that the two
common ways of evaluating the right-shift would yield the same result] is
comparatively recent.  I think the authors of C89 intended that if quality
compilers for platform X could be expected to behave a certain way before
C89 was published, and such behavior would be allowable under the Standard,
quality compilers for that platform should continue to behave that way.
Nonetheless, an attitude has emerged that programmers should not be allowed
to rely upon any behaviors not mandated by the Standard, even on platforms
where they would be useful and cheap.